# не получается запустить томкат в eclipse, Можно ли создать новый порт?

Tags: java-ee, eclipse, tomcat

Several ports (8005, 8081, 8009) required by Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Несколько портов (8005, 8081, 8009), требуемых Tomcat v9.0 сервер на localhost уже используется. Возможно, сервер уже запущен в другом процессе или системный процесс использует порт. Чтобы запустить этот сервер, вам нужно будет остановить другой процесс или изменить номер(ы) порта.

Можно ли создать новый порт?

Comment: Зачем вы английскую версию вопроса привели?

Comment: Я ее перевел на русский

Comment: Это цитата из документации? Если да, приведите пожалуйста ссылку.

Comment: нет это не цитата из документации это ошибка запуска томкат

Comment: ребят все я сам решил, оказывается нужно было отключить старые порты которые во внешке были включены, я просто взял и переименовал эти порты в самом еклипсе)))